# can't run server or bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby and Rails has been running fine on my Mac, but I'm suddenly having some problems. When I try to run the server or generate a model (i.e. use the 'rails' command in anyway) I get this error

```
/Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:187:in `stub_source_index170': uninitialized constant Gem::SourceIndex (NameError)
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:353:in `stub_rubygems'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:250:in `replace_entrypoints'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:in `setup'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/tm/Sites/anwaltythree/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from /Users/tm/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

I randomly tried to run bundle update and got this error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class
An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Following its instructions, I installed rake

```
gem install rake -v '10.0.4'
Successfully installed rake-10.0.4
Installing ri documentation for rake-10.0.4
```

However, I get the same errors with the 'rails' command and bundle update as described above.

The error is occurring across multiple project folders.

The only difference between today and yesterday (when everything worked fine) is that I installed jekyll last night and, while troubleshooting that, ran some 'sudo' commands, which I normally don't ever have to run. I have no idea whether that's related to the current problem. I'm just providing context.

I'm at a loss for what to do next. Can you suggest what I might try

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its quite possible that the versioning of ruby/gem/bundler might have switched or changed. Couple of things you could do is

1. Check what version of ruby you are on `ruby -v`.
2. Then pass in `rvm use 1.9.3` your terminal again.
3. I remember reading Gem::Package no longer supports the open method. So try updating your gem system (`gem update --system`).
4. You can then bundle your gem file again (its a good idea to update your bundle again, this could be the issue, so `gem install bundler`)
5. Make sure to delete the .lock file before bundle.

Comment: +1 for your answer, minor item - looks like Tomoko is using rbenv not rvm - maybe `rbenv versions` would indicate if they are on the right version of ruby?

Comment: I use rbenv not rvm and the ruby version didn't seem to have anything to do with the problem. however, after updating the system (it said it was already updated) and reinstalling bundler, it worked again. so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran

`gem update bundler`

Then all good to go.